# Java Swing How can I create a Color Swatch in my custom ColorChooserPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcolorchooser

I'm working on my custom ColorChooserPanel class, but I don't know how to create a ColorSwatch.

I found a class named `ColorSwatch` or something like that but its package private and I can't access it.

How can I ensure that I have a proper color chooser?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5inLI.png)?

Comment: Only the square where I can drag the mouse to choose a color, I'm able to do the other things

Comment: *"I'm able to do the other things"* Why bother, when it's all built-in to a `JColorChooser`. Sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I need to use a different Layout, since I have to put it inside a toolbar and it can't be resized, it occupies too much space in the way it is by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to think about the way this should work, to formulate your goals into action points that you can always check and see whether and how they are fulfilled:

- it should be displayed
- it should handle click events
- it should be able to return a color (the last chosen color, or a default in lack of that)

Now, a very common way of supporting color choosers is to have something like in this image:

[image]

However, this is way too complex for a first implementation. You should first have something which "works", that is, you are able to choose colors to taste success and then work out the subsequent details. Unless you say otherwise, I'm assuming that the Basic colors section is good for now. In that case, you can create a class, which contains a `JPanel`, containing clickable elements. Your `class` needs to have a `Color` member, which one can get calling a getter and which is set when a clickable item inside your `JPanel` is clicked. The clickable items can be `JPanels` on their own, for example.

If you prefer something ready-made, then kindly read these:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html

https://coderanch.com/t/332515/java/Color-Palette